# Use different WHERE-clause based on CASE outcome in SQL

Tags: mysql

I did find some answers to similar questions, but can't quite figure it out yet.

I have a MySQL table with tyres in it. A tyre record consists of the columns:

1. brand
2. width
3. height
4. diameter
5. price

When the width, height and diameter match certain values, I need to select tyres of certain brands. If it doesn't, I need to select tyres of other, partially overlapping, brands.

What I need to achieve, in bogus-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tyres
IF (width = 275 AND height = 55 AND diameter = 18)
    OR (width = 270 AND height = 55 AND diameter = 17)
    OR (width = 290 AND height = 45 AND diameter = 19)
THEN WHERE_CLAUSE = "WHERE brand = 'dunlop' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'vredestein'"
ELSE WHERE_CLAUSE = "WHERE brand = 'goodyear' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'ferrari'"
```

I've tried many notations like below, but (obviously) keep getting syntax error #1064:

```
SELECT * FROM tyres
CASE WHEN width = '275' AND height = '55' AND diameter = '18' THEN " WHERE brand = 'dunlop' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'vredestein'"
ELSE " WHERE brand = 'goodyear' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'ferrari'"
```

How can I use a specific WHERE clause, based on the outcome of the CASE statement?

Comment: Try to put the case statement into the WHERE clause.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on this one? How can you differentiate the possible result on this one? Have you tried `UNION ALL` for each criteria?

Comment: I've tried this, but still get syntax error #1064: `SELECT * FROM tyres
WHERE
CASE WHEN width = '275' AND height = '55' AND diameter = '18' THEN " brand = 'dunlop' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'vredestein'"
ELSE " brand = 'goodyear' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'kinforest'"`

Comment: @Edper I haven't, but will look in to it as it looks promising.

Comment: If `width = 275 AND height = 55 AND diameter = 18` the brand is `DUNLOP` or you want it `'dunlop' OR 'michelin' OR 'vredestein'`?

Comment: @Edper in that case it has to be either 'dunlop' OR 'michelin' OR 'vredestein'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM tyres
WHERE width = 275 AND height = 55 AND diameter = 18
AND (brand = 'dunlop' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'vredestein')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tyres
WHERE width <> 275 OR height <> 55 OR diameter <> 18
AND (brand = 'goodyear' OR brand = 'michelin' OR brand = 'ferrari')
```

The first `SELECT` is the `THEN` portion in your post and the second `SELECT` is the `ELSE` portion.

Comment: This does exactly what I need. It's a little slow though, but that might have to do with there being way more columns than I mentioned, so I'll replace the `SELECT *` with just the columns I need.

Comment: Good that it work for you and good point on selecting only the columns you need. Happy coding and GOD bless.